# How to merge multiple rows in Snowflake

Tags: etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a stored procedure that processes some json data and does insers.

```
INSERT INTO SRC (C1,C2,C3,I1,I2,I3) VALUES('ONE1', 'TWHO1', 'THREE1', 12,22,32),('ONE2', 'TWHO2', 'THREE2', 11,12,12);
```

Notice the example inserts two rows at at time, in real life scenario the number of new rows is very large and limited only by the snowflake query size.
The problem I need to solve is to update the existing rows based on some columns or insert if they do not exist. In this example lets say there is already a row with first field C1='ONE1'. That would be replaced with incoming row. The second row with C1='ONE2' would be inserted if there is no duplicate.
Now if this was just one row I would use a merge statement, but I am not sure how to do it with multiple rows in one query. Exspecially that this procesure is already some bottleneck due to sheer volume of new rows ( several hundred thousands at a time ).  Maybe delete the matching rows first and the insert all new rows ?

Comment: By "limited only by the snowflake query size" do you mean they're being passed as literal values in a SQL statement? Can you get the values any other way, such as in a file, a table, or query?

Comment: when we first did a lift in shift, we where passing 1MB SQL insert statement into snowflake. "it works" but avoid it, instead put the data into a file in S3 and COPY from that. Also insert new and update other, is what the MERGE function does. You can do multi-table inserts. all very nice.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim sure I know what merge does that's why I mentioned it. Can you give an example sql for the case above that would merge based on more than one row? Also can you be more spcific what is the problem with large queries ? From what I tested here it is inserting half a million rows in a few seconds. The data is not structured so it would be very hard to transofrm using only SQL.

Comment: large SQL queries take more time to "compile", which back in 2016 did cost, but you pay for it now. Also back in 2016 the compile times on the LOAD impact compile time on READs as the compiling was on shared infrastructure. I am sure they have improved things, and if your happy, go for it, it's just way faster to push large volumes of data into really big files, and run a COPY on that than run 10-20 "max size" SQL commands.